# Modal Popup not working for Mobile

Tags: css, modal-dialog, joomla3.0

I am using modal pop-ups to for images [here](http://test.guru99.com/cloud-computing-for-beginners.html)

As you may observe, the pop-up work great for desktops, but in mobile devices they just stackup one after the other.

The code I use basically searches for all image tags and adds class modal to the images

```
 private function convertString($text, $replace_str) {
    $pos = strpos($replace_str, 'src=');
    $pos_start = strpos($replace_str, '"', $pos + 1);
    $pos_end = strpos($replace_str, '"', $pos_start + 1);
    $image_str = substr($replace_str, $pos_start + 1, $pos_end - $pos_start - 1);
    $new_str = '<a class="modal" href="'.$image_str.'">'.$replace_str.'</a>';
    $return_str = str_replace($replace_str, $new_str, $text);
    return $return_str;
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You aren't using the Boostrap modal, so I removed the incorrect tags.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is (firstly, this isn't Boostrap modal code) you have a fixed position for the modal class, which is wrapped around the image (i.e. the anchor to trigger the modal, not the modal itself). This is causing them all to display in the same place.

Wrong code:

```
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
}
```

Remove the position property and you should be fine.

Comment: i have tried exactly what you said but not working.even i have removed all the properties in .modal then also it is not working.i have changed the theme then it works perfectly.so what should i do??

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code when you changed it.

Comment: Thanks it worked!I tried your suggestiong correctly this time